# How do I get my EPG to come back on mythTV?

Tags: mythbuntu

Everything on the schedule is coming up as unknown.

I can't set up programs to record as nothing is on. Have run updates, channel scan, mythfill database. Still no EPG.

How do I get my EPG to come back on mythTV?

Comment: Is this a DVB (freeview in the UK and Australia) card that you are using?

Answer (score 2):

If your box stopped, crashed or you switched it off etc. - it is feasible one of the *mythconverg* tables got corrupted - in which case you need to run *mysqlrepair*

```
mysqlrepair -u mythtv -p mythconverg
```

It will ask you for a password - which you can find in the *.mythtv/mysql.txt* file.